# Website looks wrong in Google Chrome

Tags: image, google-chrome, css-transitions

I have this website: [hrrubin.dk](http://hrrubin.dk)

In chrome, you will notice that all images that have image switch on mouseover, are positioned wrong. This has flaw happened only recently. Maybe a cause of some changes to the chrome code.

Is the solution to make a chrome hack, so not to disturb the the rest of the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a better way to do it. You put all of those images in a sprite, and apply them as a background image to the `a` tag. Give distinct IDs to each `a` tag. Then use background positions to position them and to change them on hover. That's how its generally done.